# Incompatible destructor compiler warning when from inheriting from std::streambuf

Tags: c++, iostream, icc, streambuf

I get a ICL compiler warning when inheriting from `std::streambuf` saying that the destructor is not compatible, any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Making it a virtual destructor does not work either.

> warning #809: exception specification for virtual function
>   "CAbcBuffer::~CAbcBuffer" is incompatible with that of overridden
>   function "std::basic_streambuf<_Elem, _Traits>::~basic_streambuf [with
>   _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]"

```
class CAbcBuffer : public std::streambuf
{
    protected:
        /** Work buffer */
        char *buffer;
    public:
        explicit CAbcBuffer()
        {
            /*
            Stores the beginning pointer, the next pointer, and the end pointer for the 
            input buffer
            */
            buffer = new char[100];
            std::streambuf::setg(buffer, buffer, buffer);
        }

        ~CAbcBuffer() {
            delete [] buffer;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `throw()` declaration for your destructor. This will fix the problem:

```
~CAbcBuffer() throw() {
    delete [] buffer;
}
```

Comment: That works. I will bump you up +1 if you explain why too. I thought throwing exceptions from the destructor was a bad idea so why does `std::streambuf` do so? Also the documentation says the destructor is a no-throw, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/~streambuf/

Comment: Throwing exceptions from destructors *is* a horrible idea. But throw() means exactly that - it is a promise *not* to throw anything.

Comment: On the other hand, it's illegal for an implementation to declare the streambuf destructor no-throw.  His original code is correct, and should work on a conforming implementation.

Comment: @James: you are right. It seems you cannot turn off this behaviour in MSVC unless you omit the /Za compiler switch, which I find very counter-intuitive, as /Za should *disable* MS-specific non-standard behaviour.